# Example of a good 'middle-of-the road' c3p0 configuration for MySQL?

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

i am trying to use c3p0 in my current Spring based application. I am no database pooling expert and was wondering if there is a more or less a good example of a c3p0 configuration (in applicationContext.xml) that can be used against a MySQL database?
The pool should detect database connection loss and retries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c3o0 is dead, do not use it. Use [jdbc-pool](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/modules/jdbc-pool/)

Here's the docs, (scroll down to **How to use**) http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

Here's a good article on why is this better http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/03/12/explaining-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency-alternative-connection-pooling-module

Comment: Seems fair enough :) I am going to give this a go! Thanks for the great tip. Do you have by any change a good configuration for this connectionpool? By the way, i am trying to build it with maven but i cannot find a good repository for it... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You mean c3p0 or hibernate-c3p0?
Hibernate has taken development for C3P0 and it is very well alive.
It just published version 4.0.0 CR1, which will be out with Hibernate 4.